# Terraform for_each azure customer managed keys

Tags: automation, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to user a `for_each` to create multiple azure storage accounts and azure secrets and keys.

so far so good and managed to create everything as supposed to be using this code:

```
variable "storage-foreach" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["storage1", "storage2"]
}

variable "key-name" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["key1", "key2"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-foreach" {
  for_each                 = toset(var.storage-foreach)
  access_tier              = "Hot"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = var.location
  name                     = each.value
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.tenant-testing-test.name
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "storagesctforeach" {
  for_each     = toset(var.storage-foreach)
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  name         = each.value
  value        = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.key].primary_connection_string
  content_type = "${each.value} Storage Account Connection String"
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_table" "tableautomation" {
  for_each             = toset(var.storage-foreach)
  name                 = "UserAnswer"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.key].name
  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "client-key" {
  for_each     = toset(var.key-name)
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  name         = "Key-Client-${each.value}"
  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
  key_type = "RSA"
  key_size = 2048
}
```

This block of code works perfectly fine until when I try to create a customer managed key resource and automatically assign the keys to the storage accounts.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key" "storage-managed-key" {
  for_each           = toset(var.key-name)
  key_name           = each.value
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.value].id
  key_version        = "current"
}
```

The problem I am facing is, as I created all the previous resources with a `for_each` in the above resource is expecting a `[each.value]` in my storage account id. Which I placed but that parameter is targeting the `var.key-name`, which is throwing an error as it can't find those strings in my storage account.
I was wondering if you can help me to think about a good practice to automate this procedure and make sure that it picks up the correct key to encrypt the correct storage account id in the resource group.

Thank you very much in advance everyone, and I am sorry but I have been struggling on this block of code and how I can automate it.

Comment: Hi, could you add your storage account block to the question?

Comment: @adp Done. Sorry mate I thought I did add it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access `var.storage-foreach` items by using the `var.key-name`.

I think the following works for you:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key" "storage-managed-key" {
  count              = length(var.key-name)
  
  key_name           = var.key-name[count.index]
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[var.storage-foreach[count.index]].id
  key_version        = "current"
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect. I don't have any error during the plan and it does recognise the key, but there is an error that says "EncryptionAtRest/Customer Managed Key for this storage account" do you have any idea why this error? Thank you very much for your help adp. You are an absolute legend

Comment: Do you have a KV access policy as shown here? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_customer_managed_key

Comment: I mean, in order for your storage to be able to access the KV, an access policy should be defined.

Comment: I don't have the resources per se, but in my key_vault I have `access_policy` set for key, secrets and certificate.

Comment: Can you create a separate question for this issue? And paste a screenshot of the KV access policies page?

Comment: sure. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome .. my gut says the problem is sth to do with KV access policies.

Comment: Done my I created the post. Thank you so much. But I keep getting different errors